# Match the numerical value of the 300-character type partially off the 20 as follows in the MYSQL

Tags: mysql

Match the numerical value of the 300-character type partially off the 20 as follows in the MYSQL

```
substring('121111111111111111111221111111111111111112111111111111111111121111111111111111111211111111111111111112111111111111111111121111111111111111111211111111111111111112111111111111111111121111111111111111111211111111111111111112111111111111111111121111111111111111111211111111111111111112111111111111111111',41,58) + 
substring('121111111111111111111221111111111111111112111111111111111111121111111111111111111211111111111111111112111111111111111111121111111111111111111211111111111111111112111111111111111111121111111111111111111211111111111111111112111111111111111111121111111111111111111211111111111111111112111111111111111111',41,58)




1211111111111111111112111111111111111111121111111111111111 + 1211111111111111111112111111111111111111121111111111111111 =
2422222222222222222224222222222222222222242222222222222222
```

We want to get the results as described above, but the following results are obtained. cast () and convert () by using the function is the same even if the cast. Help please.

```
2422222222222222200000000000000000000000000000000000000000.0000000000000000000000000000000
```

Answer (score 0):

Try converting to `DECIMAL(65)`, and then perform the addition.

```
 SELECT CONVERT(SUBSTRING( stringval  ,41,58),DECIMAL(65))
      + CONVERT(SUBSTRING( stringval  ,41,58),DECIMAL(65))
```

Comment: I was completed in your favor. Thank you very much.